# How to registerOutParameter of type Raw in Java

Tags: java, oracle, procedure, callable-statement, raw-types

I have Oracle procedure named enter that returns RAW type as result.When I want to register out parameter named 'ret' I get this error :

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Parameter Type Conflict: sqlType=-2
```

This is my java method and import statement:

```
import org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.Raw;

public Raw enter(int pid) {
    Connection connection;
    CallableStatement cstmt;
    try {
        connection = cscadaDataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{ CALL process_logging.PROCESSMONITOR_ENTER(?,?) }");
        cstmt.setInt(1, pid);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.RAW , "ret");
        cstmt.execute();

        Raw result = (Raw) cstmt.getObject(2);

        connection.commit();
        return result;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

How can I get this output parameter of RAW type in Java? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the import for `Raw` look like? I would have thought it needed to be `oracle.sql.RAW`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. My procedure spec is like this :
    PROCEDURE PROCESSMONITOR_ENTER(pidBr IN NUMBER,ret out RAW)  
In procedure in variable ret I return sys_guid()

Comment: In the Java code, what are you importing to get the `Raw` class?

Comment: import org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.Raw;  for return type of method and 
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;  for oracle types in registeroutparameter.  problem is this second part

Comment: Try using `oracle.sql.RAW` instead of `org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.Raw`.

Comment: No. It's not problem in return type of the method. i get error on this line : cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.RAW , "ret");
OracleTypes.Raw is the problem. i tried Types.OTHER, Types.JAVA_OBJECT, etc...  and none seems to work

Comment: If you're not prepared to try the things that get suggested then, well, I'm not prepared to help further.

Comment: I didn't say that. I tried your suggestion. It didn't help. I am sorry if you misunderstand me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[void registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex,
                        int sqlType,
                        String typeName)
                          throws SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api//java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Parameters:
>       parameterIndex - the first parameter is 1, the second is 2,...
>       sqlType - a value from Types
>       typeName - **the fully-qualified name of an SQL structured type**

You have parameter name, not parameter type.

Try use just:

`cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.RAW)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did like you said and it solve my problem.